# Error starting spring session + redis in docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, redis, spring-session

I'm trying to complete spring security with angular tutorial from the spring site:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ , but I hit the wall during the part about storing data in the redis, because I'm getting the error.

The error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSess
ionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not ge
t a resource from the pool
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at com.angtut.AngtutResourceApplication.main(AngtutResourceApplication.java:21) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:198) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:345) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:223) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53) ~[jedis-2.8.1.jar:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:99) ~[jedis-2.8.1.jar:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:12) ~[jedis-2.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:191) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:164) ~[jedis-2.8.1.jar:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:80) ~[jedis-2.8.1.jar:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1677) ~[jedis-2.8.1.jar:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:87) ~[jedis-2.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49) ~[jedis-2.8.1.jar:na]
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158) ~[jedis-2.8.1.jar:na]
        ... 36 common frames omitted

[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRe
disHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: C
ould not get a resource from the pool
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
        at com.angtut.AngtutResourceApplication.main(AngtutResourceApplication.java:21)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:345)
        at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:99)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:12)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:191)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:164)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:80)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1677)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:87)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
        ... 36 more
```

The redis is started in docker using docker-compose:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

Code of my Application class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.HeaderHttpSessionStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.UUID;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class AngtutResourceApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AngtutResourceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @CrossOrigin(origins="*", maxAge=3600, allowedHeaders={"x-auth-token", "x-requested-with"})
    public Message home() {
        return new Message("Hello World");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    HeaderHttpSessionStrategy sessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }


    class Message {
        private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        private String content;

        Message() {
        }

        public Message(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
    }
 }
```

Application config (ip took from docker using "docker-machine ip") :

```
spring:
  redis:
    host: 192.168.99.100
    port: 6379
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the error when your Redis server is not properly exposed from the Docker container and the application does not see it.

Try also using it without a `docker-machine` and then adapt the solution by using a container running in a `docker-machine`. For example, for me the following fixed the problem:

1. Get the Redis Docker image: `docker pull redis`
2. Run a Redis Docker container: `docker run -ti --name some-redis -d -p 6379:6379 redis`

In my case I use Maven in my Spring-Boot project and the tests try to connect to Redis. With the steps above I don't get the `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` anymore.